# MYSQL LOAD DATA INFILE ignore duplicate rows, with non-unique value columns

Tags: python, mysql, csv

**Hiya, I need to load a csv file into my mysql table. The csv is as follows:**

fruit,colour,ut

apple,green,2015-12-18

apple,orange,2015-12-18

All 3 mysql columns can't have a Unique Index. The fruit_table is as follows:

### id  |fruit   |colour  |ut

1   |apple   |green   |2015-01-01

I want to IGNORE rows which already in the database for fruit AND colour. So my final table would be:

```
+--------------------------------+
|      fruit   colour      ut    |
+--------------------------------+
| 1   apple   green   2015-01-01 |
| 2   apple   orange  2015-12-18 |
+--------------------------------+
```

I can't make 'fruit' or 'colour' unique value columns. I've tried many variations of

```
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'fruit.csv'
    IGNORE 
    INTO TABLE fruit_table
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (fruit,colour)
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a composite uniqe index over the 2 fields  fruit and colour.

```
ALTER TABLE fruit_table 
ADD UNIQUE KEY (`fruit` , `colour`) ;
```

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. Thanks Bernd